# Why is FFmpeg suddenly throwing “Segmentation fault: 11” errors and creating output files with only “ftypisomisomiso2avc1mp4freemdat” as content?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, subtitles

I am running FFmpeg version 4.3.1 — as installed via Homebrew — on macOS Catalina (10.15.7). And this morning I was running a standard FFmpeg command to I use merge MP4 and SRT subtitles:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -i input.srt -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng output.mp4
```

When it suddenly failed with these lines on the screen:

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:2 (subrip (srt) -> mov_text (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Segmentation fault: 11
```

This is weird to me since I used the exact same command a few days back — and it the past even — without any issues.

Checking the output file itself only shows the following as content; seems to have died immediately on creating headers for the output file:

```
ftypisomisomiso2avc1mp4freemdat
```

Checking a few of my usable MP4 files shows that `ftypisomisomiso2avc1mp4freemdat` is part of the initial content of those files as well. But the MP4 files that work clearly have headers and binary content past that.

Why the heck this this suddenly happening on such a simple content copy/merge command? This command does nothing more than merge an MP4 video with subtitles without transcoding content and should take less than a second or so to do its job.

The only thing of note is a regularly run `brew update` and `brew upgrade` with little to no issues. But I am assuming a recent FFmpeg upgrade caused this issue. Here is the full version output on my macOS machine for reference:

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.21)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
```

What can be done to fix this? Simply wait for a new version/patch of FFmpeg to be released to address the issue? Is there perhaps a parameter that can be added to that command to ensure the command works as expected?

Comment: See if `brew install ffmpeg --HEAD` fixes it. This will install the latest version from the current git master branch which is always newer than any release. Alternatively, try an already compiled ffmpeg from [evermeet.cx](https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/).

Comment: While this may be an issue that is solved in a few days or so with an update/patch, the main reason I am posting this — past saving the sanity of others dealing with this — is the only results from a Google search for `skas` are exactly two posts on a Russian language Linux forum: [Such as the one](https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/development/12719041).

Comment: @llogan Tried that and I get this output: `patching file libavformat/libsrt.c
Hunk #1 FAILED at 313.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 337.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file libavformat/libsrt.c.rej`. Honestly that seems too “edgy” for a solution. Anyone/everyone using FFmpeg 4.3.1 might be facing this issue. So hopefully there is an update/patch reasonably soon. But I wonder if there is an FFmpeg parameter that can be added to the command to simply get the merge to work.

Comment: The error is from the homebrew formula attempting to apply a patch that is not valid for the newer source code; it's not really an error from ffmpeg itself. I don't have macOS, and have never used homebrew so I don't know how to stop the patching. Using "HEAD" may seem edgy, but FFmpeg is a little different. Releases are meant for those who need to stay within a specific API version. Releases are outdated even when they are released. HEAD is stable more than 99% of the time and FFmpeg encourages users to use it over releases: especially when encountering problems.

Comment: @llogan Fair enough and makes sense. But I post here for the poor schlubs out there who will might get bitten by this issue. Even if FFmpeg installed on my system right now is behind the curve, this command is as simple as it gets in FFmpeg and can even be simplified to `ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -i input.srt -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4` and fail the same way.

Comment: I would never recommend something so old like 2.8.17 when there are better solutions. Forgot to mention option #3: [homebrew-ffmpeg](https://github.com/homebrew-ffmpeg/homebrew-ffmpeg) tap which provides the option for additional features and doesn't have the patch nonsense. **Update:** I take that back: actually it also has the patch.

Comment: @llogan I modified my answer to address the core issue: My solution is a workaround to use an earlier version of FFmpeg to solve my specific issue. I don’t recommend downgrading a production install to deal with stuff like this, but if a workaround works and is quick to implement via a VM, then that is a solid option in my mind.

Comment: @slhck can you take a look at this? I believe you maintain the homebrew recipe for ffmpeg.

Comment: @Gyan Just tested and there was an update from `4.3.1_2` to `4.3.1_3` that solved this issue. Thanks again for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***NOTE**: Seems like there was an update to FFmpeg around November 6, 2020 from version `4.3.1_2` to `4.3.1_3` that solved this issue. So this was a transient bug that was cleared up. Leaving the answer up for future reference if someone else runs into similar issues.*

---

### The only solution I have to this is a workaround of using an earlier version of FFmpeg.

#### I know that FFmpeg 2.8.17 is two major versions behind version 4.3.1, but for the my purpose of quickly finding a solution to merging an MP4 with subtitles without transcoding, this solution was quick to implement and address my issue.

While I am hoping there is a parameter that can be added to the command to get past this issue, not knowing what else to do I launched an Ubuntu 16.04 VM I have setup in VirtualBox, installed FFmpeg on it, copied the video and subtitles to that Ubuntu 16.04 VM, ran the same command and all worked as expected.

The installed version of FFmpeg on Ubuntu 16.04 if you simply run `sudo aptitude install ffmpeg` is 2.8.17; which is definitely a lower version that I have via Homebrew (4.3.1) in macOS but for purely merging subtitles, it did the job.

Here is the full version output for FFmpeg on the Ubuntu 16.04 VM for reference:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.17-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
```